# How to join multiple columns in two tables for same data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

`User` table has `userid` and `Username` columns. `Location` table has `createduserid` and `modifieduserid` columns.

I want to display `createdusername` and `modifieduser` using join between these two tables.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Top 
    CU.UserName AS [Created UserName], LG.CreatedBy, 
    cu.UserName AS [Modified UserName], lg.ModifiedBy
FROM 
    locationtablep as LG
JOIN 
    Usertable as CU ON CU.CoreUserID = lg.ModifiedBy
```

Using this query I get only Modified user name but not the createduser name.

Help me to get both username in single query?

Comment: You're pulling CU.Username twice and assigning it to different names.

Comment: Yes, because I want to display created user name and modified user name on the basis of their userid.

Answer (score 3):

You need to join the same table twice:

```
SELECT CU.UserName AS [Created UserName],  LG.CreatedBy, 
       MU.UserName AS [Modified UserName], LG.ModifiedBy
FROM locationtablep as LG
JOIN Usertable as CU
  ON CU.CoreUserID = lg.CreatedBy
JOIN Usertable as MU
  ON MU.CoreUserID = lg.ModifiedBy
```

Comment: Thanks for response. After using above query I get same user name in created username and Modified username columns. Actually data is created by some one and edited by some other person. So name is different.

Comment: That's why the different joins are joining to CreatedBy and ModifiedBy columns

Comment: Correct. Let me explain one more time. Example : I have created a post. And after some time that post edited by my colleague. Suppose my userid is 001 and my colleague id 006. So Createdby 001 and Modifiedby 006. The result should Created UserName : LinuxRakesh CreateBy :001 Modified UserName : LinuxKapoor Modifieby: 006. But using your query I get same username in created Username and Modified user column. Created UserName : LinuxRakesh CreateBy :001 Modified UserName : LinuxRakesh Modifieby: 006. I want the username on basis of their id's.

Comment: If CoreUserID is the correct field in Usertable then that's what this does, if there actually is also UserID field that has different values, then of course you have to use that.